# search whole table using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have inserted some data to this table:

```
mysqli_query($con,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sitelist(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
data1 VARCHAR(200),
data2 TEXT )");
```

Then I am going to search in this table with this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sitelist  WHERE data2 LIKE '%$keyword%' ";

$result = $con->query($sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count>0) { $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );

$link=$row['data2'];

echo $link; }
```

It works but echo just first data1 that its data2 have match with keywords, not the whole results!

How do I fix it?

Comment: the fetch() returns a **SINGLE** row of results, not the entire result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a loop like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo $row['data2'] . '<br>';
}
```